# Pusher in android not working

Tags: android, ruby-on-rails, pusher

I am new to pusher , I just want to send notification message to android app .
I created new app from pusher account and then putted code (that was given on Getting Started tab) , to my android app and server code to my rails server .

But now when I send event from Debug Console , on Getting started page there it shows on dialog "Hello"  , but on my android app it doesn't show any message .
Here is my android code .

```
Pusher pusher = new Pusher("MY_APP_KEY");

    Channel channel = pusher.subscribe("test_channel");

    channel.bind("my_event", new SubscriptionEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onEvent(String channelName, String eventName, final String data) {
            System.out.println(data);
            a.setText(data);
        }
    });

    pusher.connect();
```

Am I doing everything correct or not ?

Does it show message in app on sending event from Debug Console on pusher website ?

Comment: How are you sending your notification? Are you sending it to the correct `channel`?

Comment: Yes , I am sending by Debug Console , with correct channel .

Answer (score 2):

I know it might be late, but I was having the same issue.

Make sure you have added

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

to your AndroidManifest.xml

It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Did you set a cluster on the getting started? If you did, then your android app should include something like this:

```
PusherOptions options = new PusherOptions();
options.setCluster("YOUR_SELECTED_CLUSTER");
Pusher pusher = new Pusher("YOUR_APP_ID",options);
```

Comment: Hi, have you tried to change the order of how your doing everything ? 
On my example I do: (pusher.connect) then (pusher.subscribe) and I end with ( channel.bind).

My example is working fine, if it does not work out for you I can share de code.

Comment: Thanks for reply , yes I tried change order now , and its not working , I have left pusher and not going to use it but I would like to learn how to use it ,  please share the code. And also if you can show how to setup at pusher dashboard and how to test it .

Comment: Hope this helps, it may have some errors because I did it really fast, but the pusher sending data to the android app works awesome. 

https://github.com/cfvalencia9277/Android_PusherTest